# Unexpected session logout php

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have built a very basic script that allow users to login, for some reason the first time I login in, after Im on the home page if I click away  I get logged out. The weird thing is that it only happens the first time. So If I login again I cant navigate around without any problem.

It feels like an automatic logged out after first login.

Any ideas???

thanks before hand.

Here is my logic to perform the login

```
function client_email_exists($email){
require(PATH . '/core/model/db_connect.php');

try{
    $query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(client_id) 
        FROM clients 
        WHERE client_email = :email
        ");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}catch(Exception $e){
    include_once(PATH . "/core/view/error.php");
    exit();
}

return $query->fetchColumn() ? true : false;

}

function login($email, $password) {
require(PATH . '/core/model/db_connect.php');

$user_id = user_id_from_email($email);

try{
    $query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(client_id) 
        FROM clients
        WHERE client_email = :email 
        AND client_pass = :pass
        ");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':pass', md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}catch(Exception $e){
    include_once(PATH . "/core/view/error.php");
    exit();
}

return $query->fetchColumn() ? $user_id : false;

}

function login($email, $password) {
require(PATH . '/core/model/db_connect.php');

$user_id = user_id_from_email($email);

try{
    $query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT COUNT(client_id) 
        FROM client_users 
        WHERE client_email = :email 
        AND client_pass = :pass
        ");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':pass', md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}catch(Exception $e){
    include_once(PATH . "/core/view/error.php");
    exit();
}

return $query->fetchColumn() ? $user_id : false;

}

/* [0] ==> Login Validation */
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $messages[] = '<p class="alert alert-danger">Necesitas introducir email y Contraseña</p>';  
} elseif (client_email_exists($email) === false) {
    $messages[] = '<p class="alert alert-danger">No podemos encontrar tu email o nombre de usuario, asegurate de que estás registrado!</p>';
} else {

    $login = login($email, $password);
    if($login === false){
        $messages[] = '<p class="alert alert-danger">La combinación es incorrecta!</p>';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['client_login'] = $login;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}   
}
```

Then To check if the users are logged in I use this function, located in all users pages bellow session_start()

```
function login_protect(){
   if(!isset($_SESSION['client_login']) OR empty($_SESSION['client_login'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
   }
}
```

This would be a an example of a page.php, please note session_start() is declared in config.php

```
 <?php
    // ==> Model Code
    require_once('config.php'); // session_start() included here
    require_once(PATH . '/core/model/main.php');
    require_once(PATH . '/core/model/contingencies.php');

    // ==> Controller Code
    login_protect();
    $page = "contingencies";
    include_once(PATH . '/core/controller/date_logic.php');
    $contingencies = get_contingencies($show_month, $show_year);

    // ==> View Code 
    include_once(PATH . '/core/view/header.php');
    include_once(PATH . '/core/view/contingencias.tmpl.php');
    include_once(PATH . '/core/view/footer.php');
```

Cheers!

Comment: I may be mistaken, but you only set `$_SESSION['client_login']`. On `login_protected()`, however, you query `$_SESSION['admin_login']`.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I recently used the same code for another app and might have copied code from two sources, thanks anyway for spotting that, will edit it in a sec!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

I was having this issue when posting to the login form without the www. so the session was not being stored properly as if takes it as another domain.